# How do I query a mysqli select with "one more row backwards"?

Tags: mysql

Let's have a table called `weights`, in which I have my weight entries, like this:

```
id | time       | weight
1  | 1328140800 | 140
2  | 1328400000 | 142
3  | 1328659200 | 141
4  | 1329004800 | 144
5  | 1329044800 | 148
```

`time` is in unixtime and the entries are at **random** times. I can entry my weight every hour, or I can entry my weight every month.

Now, I want to echo a graph of my weight during a certain time range, but for that, I also need **one more weight before that time range.**

Example:

I'm requesting my weight WHERE:

```
`time` >= 1328659200 AND `time` <= 1329044800
```

This query will return these rows:

```
3  | 1328659200 | 141
4  | 1329004800 | 144
5  | 1329044800 | 148
```

And to these I need to add one more row before them. That would be this:

```
2  | 1328400000 | 142
```

How can I achieve this?

Let's say the my query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM `weights`
WHERE `time` >= 1328659200 AND `time` <= 1329044800
```

Comment: FYI: your database is called `mysql`, not mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `UNION` query and limit result of second query to 1 ordering by time DESC, this should add your previous entry to your result

```
SELECT *
FROM `weights`
WHERE `time` >= 1328659200 AND `time` <= 1329044800
UNION
SELECT *
FROM `weights`
WHERE `time` < 1328659200
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: As per the mysql manual, UNION sounds like it's exactly what I'll need. I'll accept this when I find it working, but I already think this is the correct answer! Thanks!

Comment: @RichardRodriguez I thought it to be the best solution to work this out, you are welcome mate ;)